# What do the outputs of the function dlmSmooth from R's dlm package mean?

Tags: r, smoothing, dlm

In the vignette for the R package dlm: [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf) on page 12, the author runs the function `dlmSmooth` to smooth the data and the function returns an object which is assigned to `gasSmooth`. Now, `gasSmooth$s` is described in the [package help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dlm/versions/1.1-5/topics/dlmSmooth) as:

> Time series (or matrix) of smoothed values of the state vectors. The series starts one time unit before the first observation.

They say:

> Based on the fitted model, we can compute the smoothing estimates of
>   the states. This can be used to obtain a decomposition of the data into a
>   smooth trend plus a stochastic seasonal component, subject to measurement
>   error.

and then run:

```
gasSmooth <- dlmSmooth(lGas, mod = dlmGas)
x <- cbind(lGas, dropFirst(gasSmooth$s[,c(1,3)]))
colnames(x) <- c("Gas", "Trend", "Seasonal")
```

The author in the vignette selects to plot columns 1 and 3 of this timeseries matrix, but how do they know that these states represent the smoothed trend and the seasonal trend?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this :
http://gradientdescending.com/state-space-models-for-time-series-analysis-and-the-dlm-package/

it says "The main output here is s. Again there are 13 columns, the first 2 from the linear trend model and the last columns from the seasonal component."